# Magento 2 Layered Navigation Not Displaying Price

Tags: magento2, product, category, attributes, layered-navigation

I have enabled Layered Navigation in my admin, as well as enabling some product attributes to be used within it.

However, it's not displaying on my category page. I have the category anchored and ensured that the product attribute is set to "filter with results" but nothings working.

It actually doesn't even display in the source code. I've tried several different extensions but these don't work either as they are extending the functionality of the default layered navigation.

The only attribute that actually shows on the layered navigation is a custom product attribute set as a dropdown.

Comment: Can you please confirm that all product price is same or different ?

Comment: Hi, I just changed one of my test products to use a different price and it's now working. Very strange that it doesn't work with products that have the same price, but thank you for bringing this to my attention.

Comment: This is not display because if you have same value for all then you do not have any value for filter.